# Batch script to remove rows in a CSV that are empty for a certain column

Tags: csv, batch-file

Lets say Im having the following entries:

```
*ARTNR;*BESTAND;*HERSTARTNR;*WG;*WG2;*LWG;*LWG2
1000;2758;;PAS;;Passive Bauelemente;
5800;0;;PAS;MIC;Passive Bauelemente;Microchip Technology
5801;0;;AKT;AMP;Aktive Bauelemente;TE connectivity
5802;0;;PAS;;Passive Bauelemente;
5803;0;"PDZ 4,3B  7""SOD323";AKT;;Aktive Bauelemente;
5804;0;;MEC;HON;Elektromechanik;Honeywell
5805;0;;MEC;;Elektromechanik;
5806;0;;MEC;;Elektromechanik;
5807;0;;MEC;HON;Elektromechanik;Honeywell
5809;0;;AKT;ORS;Aktive Bauelemente;Osram Opto Semiconductors
5810;0;61240090;MEC;;Elektromechanik;
5811;0;AT89C55WD-24PU;AKT;ATM;Aktive Bauelemente;Atmel
5815;0;;MEC;;Elektromechanik;
5816;0;;MEC;;Elektromechanik;
```

I now want to remove all rows that are empty on the colum, *HERSTARTNR like
the first row. Is this possible with a batch script?

Thank you

Comment: it's very easy with python

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the header row, test for non-semicolons in the first two columns.

In Windows:

```
findstr /v "^[^;]*;[^;]*;;" old.csv >new.csv
```

In *nix:

```
grep -P -v '^[^;]*;[^;]*;;' old.csv >new.csv
```

Linux example:

```
rojo@pico:~$ grep -P -v '^[^;]*;[^;]*;;' old.csv > new.csv
rojo@pico:~$ cat new.csv
*ARTNR;*BESTAND;*HERSTARTNR;*WG;*WG2;*LWG;*LWG2
5803;0;"PDZ 4,3B  7""SOD323";AKT;;Aktive Bauelemente;
5810;0;61240090;MEC;;Elektromechanik;
5811;0;AT89C55WD-24PU;AKT;ATM;Aktive Bauelemente;Atmel
```

Windows example:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>findstr /v "^[^;]*;[^;]*;;" old.csv > new.csv
C:\Users\me\Desktop>type new.csv
*ARTNR;*BESTAND;*HERSTARTNR;*WG;*WG2;*LWG;*LWG2
5803;0;"PDZ 4,3B  7""SOD323";AKT;;Aktive Bauelemente;
5810;0;61240090;MEC;;Elektromechanik;
5811;0;AT89C55WD-24PU;AKT;ATM;Aktive Bauelemente;Atmel
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the trick?

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\d+;\d+;;/' file.csv
```